# Symfony error page only when inside the custom route

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-3.3

I am currently developing a re-usable bundle, wherein I am making additional routes (set inside routing.yml + loaded with Routing Loader mechanism). All start with `/admin` (yes, this is an admin bundle). I have currently my own 404 page in my web-application (the main one). And I am trying to make that if the user is inside the admin bundle error he will see another error pages.

I made it with my own custom `ExceptionListener` (inside the custom admin bundle!) as following

```
  class ExceptionListener
  {
     //...
     public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
     {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $response = new Response();

        //...

        $response->setContent($this->templating->render($templateName, [
            'statusCode' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'page' => $page
        ]));
        $event->setResponse($response);
     }
  }
```

and in the bundle's `services.yml`:

```
 admin.exception_listener:
    class: ....\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    calls:
        - ["setTemplating", ["@templating"]]
        - ["setKernel", ["@kernel"]]
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Now it works fine, all custom bundle's error pages are shown. But they are being shown everywhere, even in the main application route fails.

How do I separate when to show application error pages and when to show custom-bundles?

Comment: you can only have 1 exception handler afaik, but you could listen for an event coming from your admin bundle as described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: @DarkMukke, can you please tell me how to make Exception Subscriber subscribe only to exceptions that happen in one bundle of the web-app? I don't know where the other answer below had gone :0

Comment: I created the Exception Subscriber inside my custom bundle, but it behaves exactly as Exception Listener from my post. I can't make it to subscribe/listen to only one bundle's route error's. :(

Comment: If it's a 404 page that doesn't exist, how do you know what page/bundle the user was trying to load?  Just if it starts with `/admin` but doesn't exist or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want a different 404 page if the user attempts to visit a route that begins with `/admin` but doesn't exist.  You can do that in your `onKernelException()` method via:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();

// check if request starts with /admin
if (substr($request->getRequestUri(), 0, strlen('/admin')) === '/admin') {
    // load admin 404 template
    $response->setContent(/* ... */);
} else {
    // load site 404 template
    $response->setContent(/* ... */);
}

$event->setResponse($response);
```

I also notice you're not explicitly checking for a 404 page, which you should probably do via:

```
if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    /* set your template response here */
}
```

Comment: I don't quite like this decision as it will be showing admin error page to any /admin/sdfsdf route and not only admins will see it. But I guess there are no other solution

Comment: Not true. You can expand my answer to pull in the security context and check if the user is logged in and has the admin role as additional conditions